# What is another word for severe consequences?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am trying not to overuse the words "severe consequences". I am describing how different entrepreneurs are responding to a crisis differently.

For example in this sentence:

> An entrepreneur was forced to recognize the severe consequences of knowledge-shortage and act accordingly.

What do you think another word for severe consequences is?

Comment: Schematize “An entrepreneur was forced to recognize the severe consequences of knowledge-shortage and act accordingly” as “An X was forced to recognize the Y of U and V”, and note that U (“knowledge-shortage”) and V (“act accordingly”) are not properly parallel.  (Also, “knowledge-shortage” is totally clunky.)

Comment: You asked for a single word answer. Are you also considering the multi-word phrases being offered? If, so, would you change your tags?

Comment: Well, (very) colloquially: Aw shit!!

Comment: Yes jwpat7 multi words are fine as well

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Ramification**

> a complex or unwelcome consequence of an action or event.

Answer (score 20):

How about "Serious repercussions"?

Answer (score 9):

[Fallout](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fallout) generally suggests negative connotations:

> - a secondary and often lingering effect, result, or set of consequences ;have to take a position and accept the political fallout — Andy Logan.

Source: www.merriam-webster.com

Answer (score 3):

You may use **Detrimental effects** to denote the case:

> An entrepreneur was forced to recognize the *detrimental effects* of knowledge-shortage and act accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider ***bitter fruits***.

> the unpleasant results of something
>
> *Disease and malnutrition are the bitter fruits of an inefficient social healthcare policy.*
>
> <sup>http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+bitter+fruits</sup>

Comment: This would be a good one for when you want to tone it down, but when discussing a heated topic like the healthcare system, saying disease and malnutrition are "bitter fruits" kind of trivializes the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Single words that come to mind are, in decreasing order of their sense of severity:

**penalty**, **damages**, **cost**, **price**

Comment: I like "damages". Dunno why you were down-voted.

Answer (score 1):

Pitfall might fit in.
An entrepreneur was forced to recognize the **pitfalls** of knowledge-shortage and act accordingly.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pitfalls
=>An unapparent source of trouble or danger; a hidden hazard

Answer (score 0):

The right word would be “ramification(s)”. It means the complex or unwelcome consequences of an action or event.

Comment: _Ramifications_ is a great word to describe extended and difficult-to-anticipate consequences. However, I don't usually associate the term specifically with **severe** consequences, which is the core meaning that the questioner wants to convey. Please consider adding to your answer a dictionary definition that confirms this sense of the word _ramifications_.

Comment: "Ramification" was already given in [another answer from 2014](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/198009/191178), with that exact same definition. Please be sure to read all the answers before posting to ensure that you're not just repeating things. Also, you need to cite the sources for your definition.